# composer error "minimum-stability" setting

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to install this [package](http://knpbundles.com/Exeu/ExeuAmazonECSBundle)

ExeuAmazonECSBundle

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    .
    .
    .
    "exeu/amazon-ecs-bundle": "dev-master"

},
```

then

```
sudo php composer.phar update exeu/amazon-ecs-bundle
```

However it indicates two error potential, I have confirmed it is not type.

my setting is

```
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
```

and I can install other bundle as 'dev-master'

How can I slove this?

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for exeu/amazon-ecs-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by exeu/amazon-ecs-bundle[dev-master].
    - exeu/amazon-ecs-bundle dev-master requires exeu/amazon-ecs-php dev-master -> no matching package found.
  Problem 2
    - exeu/amazon-ecs-bundle dev-master requires exeu/amazon-ecs-php dev-master -> no matching package found.
    - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.2.x-dev requires exeu/amazon-ecs-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by exeu/amazon-ecs-bundle[dev-master].
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.2.x-dev].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear about what the problem is.

You need to contact the guy wrote that library and ask him to also publish the library 'exeu/amazon-ecs-php' which apparently 'exeu/amazon-ecs-bundle' [is dependent on](https://github.com/Exeu/ExeuAmazonECSBundle/blob/master/composer.json#L17).

The package amazon-ecs-php isn't available in any stability, which is why composer is failing.

Comment: oh I see. I understand,for now I will use another bundle to access amazon API. thanks a lot